# iOS Bluetooth Low Energy Scan in Background (swift3)

Tags: ios, swift3, background, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm actually working on a Bluetooth Low Energy app on iOS, written in Swift3.
My app is working well when is in foreground (scan, connect, exchange data..) with CoreBluetooth whereas, I want it to work in background (the first step is to scan peripheral in background).

I read about the subject so I already added the Background modes for the BLE (I added all the background modes so the issue is not there).

[image: Image of my Background Modes]

So, in my code, when I enter in the `applicationDidEnterBackground` method, I call the `initCBCentralManager` method. This is working well because it then go in the `centralManagerDidUpdateState` and in the "Powered On" state.
My `scan` function is called so that's not the problem.

But, after the `scan` method is called, nothing happens, I never get `didDiscover peripheral` called. When I use the functions in foreground (by calling my functions in `applicationWillEnterForeground` instead of `applicationDidEnterBackground`), it works, but not when it's in background.

I read that I need to discover a particular service so it's what I do (my service is `6E400001-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E` and also that `CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey` option will be ignored, but if I change it to false, nothing more happens.

So, how am I supposed to scan Bluetooth Low Energy peripheral when I enter in background ?

Here is my code :

```
import CoreBluetooth  

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate, CBCentralManagerDelegate {

var _manager : CBCentralManager?

func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    initCBCentralManager()
}

func initCBCentralManager() {
    var dic : [String : Any] = Dictionary()
    dic[CBCentralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey] = false
    _manager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
}

public func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
    switch central.state {
    case .poweredOff:
        print("State : Powered Off")
    case .poweredOn:
        print("State : Powered On")
        scan()
    case .resetting:
        print("State : Resetting")
    case .unauthorized:
        print("State : Unauthorized")
    case .unknown:
        print("State : Unknown")
    case .unsupported:
        print("State : Unsupported")
    }
}

func scan()
{
    print("SCAN")
    let service = "6E400001-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E"
    var service_cbbuid:[CBUUID] = [CBUUID(string: service)]
    _manager?.scanForPeripherals(withServices: service_cbbuid, options: [CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey:true])
}

func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
    print("BACKGROUND_SCAN -> \(peripheral.name.unsafelyUnwrapped) \(RSSI)dBm")
}
```

Comment: Just adding `Background Modes` to your app's info plist is not actually enough for running in background. 
For your bluetooth background scans, just the external accessory communication background mode is enough.
However, this will only report new peripherals, not continue to scan and report the same peripherals, periodically etc. If you plan to run some custom version of this scan in background, you will have to depend on some other background mode, and actually use the said background mode, not just mention it in the plist.

Answer (score 0):

See "Background Execution" section of the iPhoneAppProgrammingGuide. In short, your app must be one of these types:

1. Apps that play audible content to the user while in the background, such as a music player app
2. Apps that keep users informed of their location at all times, such as a navigation app
3. Apps that support Voice over Internet Protocol (VoIP)
4. Newsstand apps that need to download and process new content
5. Apps that receive regular updates from external accessories

And you must add to the Info.plist as follows: Add the UIBackgroundModes key to your Info.plist file and set its value to an array containing one or more of the following strings:

1. audio—The app plays audible content to the user while in the background. (This content includes streaming audio or video content using AirPlay.)
2. location—The app keeps users informed of their location, even while it is running in the background.
3. voip—The app provides the ability for the user to make phone calls using an Internet connection.
4. newsstand-content—The app is aNewsstand app that downloads and processesmagazine or newspaper content in the background.
5. external-accessory—The app works with a hardware accessory that needs to deliver updates on a regular schedule through the External Accessory framework.

   6. bluetooth-central—The app works with a Bluetooth accessory that needs to deliver updates on a regular schedule through the CoreBluetooth framework

Note that part of the review process will be checking to make sure that your app does what it says it's doing with regard to background processing.